# Count Number of categories purchased over a year, for each week in the FY year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query which will return the number of categories a customer has purchased in over the preceding year.
I can populate this into a table fine - 
what I am struggling with is an efficient way of moving the dates forward by a week, and then re-running to append to the table.
essentially what I am looking to do is create a rolling profile for the number of categories a customer (educationNumber) has bought in over the year

The query attached obviously goes back 365 days, then a further 365 from the current date and counts how many distinct categories the customer has purchased in  - 
how do I make this a rolling time period week by week?
I would like this to be efficient as possible, as this will generate a lot of rows

Ive modified this to now add it to another table and found a way to loop through - however im now hitting a syntax error near end..
also is this the most efficient way to do what I want?

```
declare @MYDATE datetime;
set @mydate = '2015-07-13 00:00:00.000';
while @MYDATE <= '2015-08-13 00:00:00.000'


insert into #CategoryHistory
--[WorkArea_Alastair].[dbo].[CategoryHistory]
(educationNumber,
Cats ,
EstablismentGroup,
YR_DATE
)

select 
trns.EducationNumber,
Count(distinct(sub.CR_ProductCategory))as Cats,
est.EstablishmentGroup,
@MyDate as YR_WK

from tblSalesTransactionsFull trns 
inner join tblProducts prd on trns.ISBNId = PRD.ISBNId
Inner join tblsubjects sub on prd.CR_ItemGroupMajor = sub.SUBJECtID
inner join tbleducationlive edu on trns.educationNumber =     edu.EducationNumber
inner join tblEstablishmentTypes est on edu.EstablishmentType =      est.EstablishmentType
where 
transactiondate = @MYDATE
and transactiondate >= getdate()-365
and transactionstatus = 'D'
and value >= '0.01'
--and Division in ('1','2')
and est.EstablishmentGroup = 'Primary Schools'
group by trns.educationNumber,est.EstablishmentGroup 
order by trns.EducationNumber asc

set @Mydate = @mydate + 7;
end
```

Comment: please try something and ask back if you run into problems. do not ask stackoverflow to answer your problem from scratch.

Comment: I have edited -to show where I have got to, albeit with a syntax error that I cant fathom at the moment, however, is this the "right" way to do what I want?

Comment: Found the syntax error!